# Restrict function parameter types to a single case of a union type parameter

Tags: typescript

So I have a union of tuples, and I can use it to declare locals:

```
type KnownPair = ["dog", "paws"] | ["fish", "scales"];

const goodPair: KnownPair = ["dog", "paws"];

//@ts-expect-error you can't mix them:
const badPair: KnownPair = ["dog", "scales"];
```

I want to declare a function that uses the type to describe multiple parameters. I can do it with spread syntax:

```
function foo<T extends KnownPair>(...args: T) {
  console.log(`${args[0]} has ${args[1]}`);
}

const goodCall = foo("fish", "scales");

//@ts-expect-error you can't mix these, either:
const badCall = foo("fish", "paws");
```

But when I try to use conventional function parameters, it gets interesting:

```
function bar<T extends KnownPair>(a: T[0], b: T[1]) {
  console.log(`${a} has ${b}`);
}

const goodCall2 = bar("dog", "paws");

//@ts-expect-error Typescript rejects a bad explicit type argument:
const badCall2 = bar<["dog","scales"]>("dog", "scales");

// but it doesn't see any problems when inferring the type:
const shouldBeBad = bar("dog", "scales");
```

It's like each function parameter is individually checked against each case of the union. What's going on? Is it possible to declare `bar` in a way that enforces as well as `foo`?

References:

- [Playground of these examples with TS 4.2.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdgewO5wAoEMCWAnKBeKAbQCIATBAc2IBopix0kBnYgXSgB8jiAzTJgBY06TAMboANhBasA3ACh5ohHCbAoFBAlIYcALliIUu3ARLkqteoxkL5AensABYEwC0EAB6RRwD9mwEXBAEAFcocTgAcnUAW0xPKGABCFi9JRU1KAAjdB0sbAN4ZDQC-G4LYWIxSWk2O0d8PGaoJjBsCDyoBmx0WIhgCGwmJubFHlC4X0wVKB4tAB4AFSgvQbhSEeLjAoA+AAoAOmP0bAomAyWASigAb3koCMyEKUOJSn2AAwASW9PzwgABlYAF8oAJ0CNfv8mIQAIygz5XBQgxTKVTqTTaADCkgk5XmCH2vH4QisNSkLGRikcLncXh8fiGgWCYQi6GicQSSRSTAgtAgmGSQ3S6KyuVIuIk+IIhOJfEEVQYzGI1Ic9lGBHRADcIHBgDM4JJuqc+gMhiNmmN5BMpgbZrlsMtVp51ptDCUTAd0JcgaxaNlfQibvdHmKXhA3h8fn8wRCobdsiCkSi0ZlMVpJXiAEzlR3EypWZVUhrOVwebwQXz+FlQJbgaSibCYMDqDoAKyrrig6ByXQZEkwoiFSQbPbOoX6+tF6b7WeluYIjoW5koNGq4kpbAOZDX5M3dTVjWyoXUI-I0k5rQg0A5IG6gWyUliIyQKTgUEwcB4zK-FB50CgJAM4Yq0AhhBIpAAEIQFBXRLqcBZ7iIB4lkAA)
- [Typescript Handbook: Rest Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters)

Comment: This isn't exactly the point of the question, but: I don't understand why you're using generics here; is there some advantage to `T extends KnownPair` over just using `KnownPair` directly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA7PQw)?    If not, maybe remove the generics since they don't do anything.  If so, could you edit the question to demonstrate why you want them?

Comment: Good question, my example was perhaps too simplified. IIRC in my app `KnownPair` was another type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
function bar<T extends KnownPair>(a: T[0], b: T[1]) {
```

is `T[0]` is `'dog | 'fish'` and `T[1]` is `'paws' | 'scales'`, but nothing in the type information tells Typescript that they're related. I think the easiest fix is to still use your spread parameters solution, but destructure them into separate variables:

```
function bar<T extends KnownPair>(...[a, b]: T) {
  console.log(`${a} has ${b}`);
}
```

Comment: This answer works (although I would just write `function bar(...[a, b]: KnownPair) {}` instead of making it generic), but OP should note that the implementation of `bar` will still not understand that `a` and `b` are [correlated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), if that matters.  To make both the call and the implementation aware of the correlation, you pretty much need to use the `args` rest parameter.